# Sharepoint 2010 Mysite Blog branding (with publishing) not working

Tags: sharepoint, blogs, publishing, mysite

I did some branding for an intranet site for a client in SharePoint 2010 and build a solution. The solution contains some masterpages which are based on the publishing features of SharePoint. 
The client's intranet site also uses Mysite and I use feature stapling to apply the feature with the Mysite masterpage to the host and personal Mysite.

The publishing features are also activated for Mysite, so the branding is consistent with the intranet site.
This works fine. When i'm activating the feature on the mysite host, the branding is applied on both the host and the personal site.

But what still isn't working after endless trial and error is the branding on the personal blog site.
When the user clicks on the "create blog" link on his personal Mysite the new site is created. But when the blog site appears, the branding is not showing up. 
It looks like the right features are not enabled.

The only step i manually have to take to make the branding work on the blog site, is to enable publishing in the features. But thats manually, i can't make it work from within the solution.

I've tried some of the following steps:

- Activate the publishing feature with stapling (I've also tried some other available publishing features) :
  On the personal site collection and blog site :

  ```
  //default branding feature
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="0676d0e2-2acf-4ac0-9ce6-e6952a4893c5" TemplateName="SPSMSITEHOST#0" />
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="0676d0e2-2acf-4ac0-9ce6-e6952a4893c5" TemplateName="SPSPERS#0" />   

  //publishing features
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa" TemplateName="SPSPERS#0" />
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb" TemplateName="BLOG#0" />
  ```

  This makes the layout work right (publishing is activated), but i see no blog content, the contentarea is blank. Is the order of features wrong? (i've tried different orders). Why isn't there any content showing up? Are the blog features not activated?

  Maybe i need to add more features in a particularly order to be activated?
- Activate the masterpage feature to the blog:

  ```
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="0676d0e2-2acf-4ac0-9ce6-e6952a4893c5" TemplateName="SPSMSITEHOST#0" />
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="0676d0e2-2acf-4ac0-9ce6-e6952a4893c5" TemplateName="SPSPERS#0" />

  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="0676d0e2-2acf-4ac0-9ce6-e6952a4893c5" TemplateName="BLOG#0" />
  ```

  This doesn't work. The result is a blog site without branding.
- Activate the masterpage feature global instead of applying it to seperate sites.

  ```
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="0676d0e2-2acf-4ac0-9ce6-e6952a4893c5" TemplateName="GLOBAL" />
  ```

  This doesn't work. The result is a blog site without branding.

Maybe i have to find a solution in another direction: it would be great if somebody could help me with some next steps. I can't find any good information about this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find any solution to the problem i am also facing the same problem . I can help you with one thing though when you activate publishing on blog the url will go .../Pages/Default.aspx just remove the pages and you will see the Content

Comment: I have found a solution, look for my anwser down below

Comment: Hi Martjin,Everything looks fine but i am getting  a small error when  i am clicking on the blog heading its going to the default pages library

Comment: Hi Anil, what exactly do you mean with the blog heading? The title that says: Welcome to your Blog! ?

Comment: No Martijn The blog has a heading right (Recent Blog Posts) When you clcik on that it is taking to http://mysitetest/personal/testuser/Blog/Pages/default.aspx.and that an empty page.Can you please help me on that..

Answer (score 0):

Try using a WebProvisioned event handler to activate the PublishingWeb feature by code, that you could staple to blog sites.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. I have found a solution just with stapling

Comment: WebProvisioned does not fire for root sites

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem just with stapling! The solution is to first activate the SharePoint Blog feature on the Mysite Personal Site Collection. And then after that, activate the right publishing features on the Mysite Personal site collection and the Blog site.

- The order of activation is therefore important
- The Blog feature must not be activated on the Blog site itself, but on te Personal Site Collection
- Choose the right publishing features for both the Personal Site Collection and the Blog site

  ```
  <!-- 1. My own feature with Masterpage on both Mysite Host and Mysite Personal -->
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="0676d0e2-2acf-4ac0-9ce6-e6952a4893c5" TemplateName="SPSMSITEHOST#0" />
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="0676d0e2-2acf-4ac0-9ce6-e6952a4893c5" TemplateName="SPSPERS#0" />

  <!-- 2. !!SharePoint Blog feature must first be activated on the Mysite Personal-->
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="863DA2AC-3873-4930-8498-752886210911" TemplateName="SPSPERS#0"/>  

  <!-- 3. SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure on Mysite Personal: -->
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa" TemplateName="SPSPERS#0"/>
  <!-- 4. SharePoint Server Publishing on Blog: -->
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb" TemplateName="BLOG#0"/>
  ```